# ImportHTML and SUM the column

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I am looking to use the `importHTML` function for loading a page and I would like to sum a particular column in Google Spreadsheets.

But I am not having much success.

This is the URL:

```
=RIGHT(index(importhtml("http://sgx.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/annent/t82u.jsp","table",7),,4),6)
```

Comment: what URL you're thinking off?

Comment: Are you getting a specific error back? What's not actually working for you? The full function you're using could be helpful; you might not be importing the right data.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for getting back. I have attached the URL i am working with as well as the formula for google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, by using the this formula.

### Formula

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(index(importhtml("http://sgx.i3investor.com/servlets/stk/annent/t82u.jsp","table",7),,4),6)))))
```

### Explained

There are two things that need to be taken into account:

1. text to number conversion
2. error capturing

The first is done by the `VALUE` function, that returns a number. The clue as to the second point starts here. The header of the table, can't be converted into a number !! Here the `IFERROR` function will return nothing if an error arises. Now the `ARRAYFORMULA` and the `SUM` can finish it off.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Sum IMPORTHTML table](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEhtX056Qm8tcTdjM3lZZDdGUjdiaXc&usp=sharing)**